# Fyne passing changing arguments to multiple buttons

Tags: go, slice, fyne

I'm having an issue with passing dynamic arguments to a button callback with Fyne. I'm trying to create a list of buttons that when clicked will call a function with a specific string argument:

```
  clients := []fyne.CanvasObject{}
  for _, uuidStr := range uuidStrs {
    clientBtn := widget.NewButton(uuidStr, func() { server.selectClient(uuidStr))
    clients = append(clients, clientBtn)
  } 
  clientsListed := container.New(layout.NewGridLayout(1), clients...)
```

The issue is that all of the buttons, when clicked, will select the **last** client e.g. it will call `server.selectClient(uuidStr)` where uuidStr is always `uuidStrs[len(uuidStrs)-1]`, but I want each button to pass in a unique uuidStr. All of the buttons **display** the correct string, but don't pass the correct string in the callback.

How can I get the buttons, when clicked, to select the client it displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how Go re-uses variables in loop iterations. You need to "capture" the value so that the button callback func gets the right value. As follows:

```
  clients := []fyne.CanvasObject{}
  for _, uuidStr := range uuidStrs {
    uuid := uuidStr
    clientBtn := widget.NewButton(uuidStr, func() { server.selectClient(uuid))
    clients = append(clients, clientBtn)
  } 
  clientsListed := container.New(layout.NewGridLayout(1), clients...)
```